# Protecting against FileExistsError when creating a new folder

Tags: python

I am trying to create a folder named ~/.Trash (its a hidden directory) without using FileExistsError. I want to create the directory without raising an error.

```
try:
  os.mkdir('~/.Trash')
except OSError as ex:
  if ex.errno == errno.EEXIST:
    print '' #I leave it blank
  else:
    raise
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
OSError: [Error 2] No such file or directory '~/.Trash'
```

How can I create a directory protecting against FileExistsError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the tilde (`~`) does not get expanded to the home directory in Python like it does in Bash.  So you're trying to create a directory `.Trash` under the (non-existent) directory `~`.  You can use `os.path.expanduser(path)` if you need a path relative to the home directory.

```
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser('~/.Trash'))
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != os.errno.EEXIST:
        raise
```